# Statistics - Uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

[image]

For part (b), I found the CDF to be $(1-x)^n$ and I differentiated that to get the PDF of $-n(1-x)^{n-1}$.

I'm quite confused on how to calculate the Expectation of M.

My current workings are as such :

E(M) = E$\left(\frac{X_1+...+X_{10}}{10}\right)$ = $\frac 1{10}$(E$X_1$ + ... + E$X_{10}$) = $\frac 1{10}$ x 10(E$X_1$) = ...

Since all the X are uniformly distributed, my idea is that I would be able to simplify it as above but I do not know how to continue from there.

Any help would be appreciated thanks~

Answer (score 1):

1. The c.d.f. of $M$ is

   $$ F_M(x) = \begin{cases}
   0, & x \leq 0 \\
   x^{10}, & 0 < x < 1 \\
   1, & x \geq 1
   \end{cases} $$

   Differentiating this gives $f_M(x) = 10 x^9$ on $(0, 1)$ and zero outside.
2. I am not sure what led you to believe that $\mathbf{E}[M] = \mathbf{E}[\frac{1}{10}(X_1+\cdots+X_{10})]$, but this is simply not true. Since you know the p.d.f. of $M$, you can compute its expectation using the integral

   $$ \mathbf{E}[M] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_M(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} 10x^{10} \, dx = \frac{10}{11}. $$
3. Of course, you can compute $\mathbf{E}[X_1]$ using the same idea, leading to

   $$ \mathbf{E}[X_1] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X_1}(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} x \, dx = \frac{1}{2}. $$

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the help, but I have a question though, how did you get the cdf to be $x^{10}$?

Comment: @WeiXiongYeo, The standard trick is to exploit the independence to write $$ F_M(x) = \mathbf{P}[M\leq x] = \mathbf{P}\Bigg[\bigcap_{i=1}^{10}\{X_i \leq x\}\Bigg]=\prod_{i=1}^{10}\mathbf{P}[X_i\leq x]. $$ The last expression evaluates to the above formula.